# Why hardcode class name when using a logger in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net-web-api, log4net

I have seen many people write this lines of code.

```
       var logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ServiceRequestController));
```

But, why should `we hard-code the controller name`.

It is better to simply write,

```
       var logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
```

A large majority of people are writing in the first way (they hard-code the class name).
But I wonder why?

Simply one could use the latter version right ?

Or I am over-seeing something here ?

Comment: I think the reason is that the logger object is usually a static object, so there is no `this` at the time of its creation. If every instance of your class has its own logger (why?), then this would be ok.

Comment: @Steve: `this` refers to the `instance of the current class`, so it would just work fine

Comment: Steve, that does not matter. 'This' in this context is the instance of the class holding the logger and the logger variable is clearly an instance field in this context. The code will be executed when an instance of the class is created prior to the execution of the constructor.

Comment: In this case, that is true. However, the log4net examples usually refer to a static logger, which is probably why `this` isn't used for loggers much.

Comment: Even with instance members, and initializer can't access `this`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Sorry, can you please explain your comment ? I dont understand. Are you telling the above statement wont work ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. Your code works inside an instance method. But loggers are generally created in a field initializer. Field initializers never have access to `this`. Thus `private Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType())` will not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Typeof` provides you with the type at compilation time, while `this.GetType` - at execution time. Moreover, the 'hardcoded' variant is often more readable (you do not need to make the mental trip thinking about 'OK, so what does `this` signifies in this context?'

Answer (score 3):

I think its matter of taste and coding guidelines of your team. First option has better readability for me. Second one is more compact, but more confusing and as already mentioned type is defined at runtime, which can give a little performance hit. What is real performance hit in your case is local loggers. I recommend to use single *static* logger instance per type. Also for even more compact logger creation you can use current stack frame to get declaring type, like it is implemented in [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/):

```
private static Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Very clear. I am accepting the other answer for the purposes of the answerers' low reputation.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. no problem. Btw I suggest to move to NLog - I have used both libraries, and find NLog much easier to use

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I am on it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends where in the class you declare your logger; most examples make use of a static logger per class, with a logger name pulled from reflecting the containing type.

```
class MyClass
{
    private static log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger( System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType );
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Log.Info( "Doing something" );
    }
}
```

Of course in this case there is no instance of the `MyClass` object to dereference to get its type, so `typeof` is used instead.